# Python script to convert snort alert to csv

Tags: python, csv, data-conversion, snort

I'm new to python. So please support me
I want to convert from snort alert to csv with some specific value

Here are the snort alert (can read by notepad):

```
[**] [1:2015665:1] ET CURRENT_EVENTS NeoSploit - TDS [**]
[Classification: Attempted User Privilege Gain] [Priority: 1] 
03/14-14:13:24.731076 192.168.52.10:1060 -> 67.196.50.144:80
TCP TTL:57 TOS:0x0 ID:34187 IpLen:20 DgmLen:258 DF
***A**** Seq: 0xBB770235  Ack: 0x9A83A217  Win: 0x3CB8  TcpLen: 20

[**] [1:2021076:1] ET INFO SUSPICIOUS Dotted Quad Host MZ Response [**]
[Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] 
03/14-14:13:24.845200 67.196.50.144:80 -> 192.168.52.10:1060
TCP TTL:128 TOS:0x0 ID:1442 IpLen:20 DgmLen:5880 DF
***A**** Seq: 0x9A83C2E5  Ack: 0xBB77030F  Win: 0xFFFF  TcpLen: 20
```

[alert.full](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By-LXLX-tLQVdGtVY3E1QUlLbkE/view?usp=sharing),

I want to filter some information such as Alert, Src IP, Src port, Dst IP, Dst port, Protocol DgmLen and save to a csv file.

```
Alert                 SrcIP          Srcport    DstIP          Dstport  Protocol   DgmLen
ET Current event...  192.168.52.10   1060       67.196.50.144    80        TCP      258
ET INFO SUSPICIOUS   67.196.50.144    80        192.168.52.10   1060       TCP      5880
```

Comment: Post a small snippet of your data please; you are less likely to get answers if people have to download a file to view what you're working it.

Comment: @Petar: Thanks for reminding, I've edited the question

Comment: You could use a grouped regex to extract the information and then write it to one row each with ",".join(groups). What you're asking for is a CSV, but what you show is a space-delimited format.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read 6 lines to a `array`
2. Create a `dict` to hold the data you want.
3. Extract Column `Alert` from `array[0]`
4. Extract Column `SrcIP, Srcport, DstIP, Dstport, Protocol , DgmLen` from `array[2]` and `array[3]`
5. Write to CSV file using `csv.DictWriter`

Comment: @Hoang-VietNguyen: If you get stuck, add your code you have so far, to your Question.